# Split a LINQ string list

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, split

I believe this could be another easy one for you LINQ masters out there.

I have a table with a field that consists of strings delimited by "#".  After I select the field using LINQ, how can I split each of the strings into a different list?
My string list looks like:

```
#A#B#C#D#G#F
```

I used a simple LINQ query to access this:

```
from x in Special_texts
where x.Name.Equals("ExceptionList")
select x.Content
```

In the end, my list should contain:

```
A
B
C
D
G
F
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with `.Split('#')` ?

Comment: Do you want each string to be a new list item or in a new list?

Comment: Just to clarify, x.Content is #A#B#C#D#G#F and you want to return, for each special_text, a list containing A, B, C, etc ?

Comment: @TomislavMarkovski how do you remove null entries?

Comment: @Justin each string should be a list item in a new list.

Comment: @Bort that sounds right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you want a *single* list as output:

```
var list = Special_texts.Where(x=> x.Name.Equals("ExceptionList"))
                        .Select(x=> x.Content)
                        .AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(x=> x.Split(new [] {'#'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                        .SelectMany(x=> x)
                        .ToList();
```

Alternatively if you want a list of lists (one for each item in `Special_texts`):

```
var list = Special_texts.Where(x=> x.Name.Equals("ExceptionList"))
                        .Select(x=> x.Content)
                        .AsEnumerable() 
                        .Select(x=> x.Split(new [] {'#'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList())
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @BrokenGlass.  I get the following error message:  'NotSupportedException: Method 'System.String[] Split(Char[], System.StringSplitOptions)' has no supported translation to SQL.'

Comment: @inquisitive_one: These indeed can't be translated - I added an `AsEnumerable()` so the second part of the query will be executed in Linq to objects context - that should work (I hadn't seen the Linq to SQL tag)

Comment: @inquisitive_one You will need to add an .AsEnumerable() just before the select statement doing the split.  This will cause it to only try to treat the beginning of the LINQ statement as something to convert to SQL, and it will perform everything after that point in memory after fetching the result set.

Comment: Thanks @BrokenGlass.  Your suggestion is what I needed.  Sorry for the silly question.  I'm not very familiar with Lambda expressions yet, but how would you write that as a regular LINQ expression?  (I just want to get a better understanding of the query.)

Comment: My problem was unlike the original posting but looking at your suggested answer gave insight into my own. My problem with the split was that an array data type (as a string) was being returned instead of the array of elements. Adding the SelectMany after the Select(x.Split)) fixed it...Although I have no idea why...

Answer (score 2):

```
from x in Special_texts
where x.Name.Equals("ExceptionList")
select x.Content.Split('#').ToList();
```

Comment: you would need to use AsEnumerable() as rightly pointed out by the folks in the above answer.

Comment: Thanks @Akhil.  How do I remove the null or empty entries?

Comment: can you try appending .Where( x => !x.ToString().Equals("")) after the ToList()?